# interact between controller and view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a form that you can type text with a "post" button and i want that when you type something and press the post button it will show what you wrote.

**My question is: What is the code to connect between the view and the controller?**

This is the view i already created:(i also generated a home controller with a showmsg  action)

```
<h1 align="center">MicroBlog</h1>
<br><br>
  <div align="center">
  <%= form_tag( {:controller => 'home', :action => 'showmsg'}, :method => "post") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:p,@postword) %>
  <%= submit_tag("post") %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

how should the showmsg action would look like so i could show the msg?
thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller will need to access the param being sent to it, assign it to an instance variable, which your view will then be able to access.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def showmsg
    @message = params[:p]
  end
end
```

/app/views/home/showmsg.html.erb

```
...
<%= @message %>
...
```